# global beforeRouteLeave mixin not running in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I am trying to implement a global mixin in nuxt

this code:

```js
Vue.mixin({
  beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    this.$store.commit('SET_ROUTERLOADINGENABLE', false)
    next()
  }
})
```

I am registering this code by calling it in nuxt.config.js

like this: 
`plugins: ["~/plugins/loadingBrain.js"],`

but this is not working at all.
is there anything wrong with the above implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved!
i had 2 node_modules folder in my project